# How add admin grid in magento 2.0.6

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, filter

How to add admin Grid in magento 2.0.6

I want to display sold product list in that Admin Grid with order status filter

Comment: sold product means, products which is out of stock ??? or status in sales order list ??

Comment: yes Status  in sales order list like how much sold particular product and order status

Comment: And as a reference, the official documentation: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/ui-components/ui-listing-grid.html

Comment: This should help you get started. About the contents of the grid: asking for a complete module is a bit too much for the Q&A format of this
site, but if you begin building the grid and have a specific problem, feel free to ask a new question. But then add the code you have written and explain what exactly you need or what you don't understand. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the create the grid for this, Just create one order status..

Follow the below given tutorial:

[manage-order-status-in-magento-2](http://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/manage-order-status-in-magento-2/)

hope this will help..

Comment: Thank you for your response,let me check and let you know

Comment: This is general about magento 2 order status ,i want to display  product list with  sale count  and ordrer-status with  filter in my custom module admin grid

Comment: one product can belong to multiple orders with having different-2 status & one order can have multiple products.. 
as status is based on order so you can't segregate it for product...
what you can do is, list the product with number of sold units...
magneto doesn't provide the product based status... else you need to tweak which may take extra time for your module..

Comment: ok  fine How we can display product with sale count in my custom module admin grid

Comment: Kindly check `sales_order_item` Table and file with namespace `Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Item`..
then you will understand how to get the sold products & there qty ordered & cancelled given for particular that you need product...
by getting factory collection of the same you can get the exact sale of the product...Thanks

Comment: qty_shipped would be your sold quantity in single order so filter the item collection with product id & SUM the qty_shipped, you will get the exact sold  product quantity..